# Python3 - Json write value through Rest API

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to write a value in JSON through a Rest API using Python 3

I can connect and read value but I can't change value, this my code

```
import os
import requests
import pycurl
import json
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen


### Connection to interface ###
headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

data = [
  ('user[name]', 'admin'),
  ('user[password]', 'hellocpt'),
]

response = requests.post('http://192.168.0.230/sdcard/cpt/app/signin.php', headers=headers, data=data)
#print("Code Status du POST: ",response.status_code)
#print(response.content)


cookies = response.cookies


### Read firmware version ###
params = (
    ('url', '/app/objects/service/plat.Version'),
)

try:
    responseget = requests.get('http://192.168.0.230/sdcard/cpt/app/data_api.php', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)
    #print("\n\nCode Status du GET: ",responseget.status_code)
    data = responseget.json()
    print (data) # Display JSON return
    print ("Firmware version: ",data['response']['data'][0]['slots'][0]['value'],"\n")

except ValueError:
    print ("Json Error")


### Try to change value of sedona object ###    
params = (
    ('url', '/app/objects/EasyIO/int.in'),
)
data =  {
        'path': '/app/objects/EasyIO/int.in',
        'type': 'int',
        'value': '100',
        'slotType': 'property',}


writeValue = requests.post('http://192.168.0.230/sdcard/cpt/app/data_api.php', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, data=data)
print(writeValue) # Actually return 200


### Read sedona objects to check if post is working######
params = (
    ('url', '/app/objects/EasyIO/int.out'),
)
readvalue = requests.get('http://192.168.0.230/sdcard/cpt/app/data_api.php', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies,)
dataInt = readvalue.json()
print(dataInt)
print(dataInt['response']['data'][0]['slots'][0]['value'])


os.system("pause")
```

output

```
{'response': {'resultCode': 0, 'data': [{'path': '/service/plat', 'type': 'easyioFW::EasyIOPlatform', 'childNum': '0', 'slots': [{'name': 'Version', 'slotType': 'property', 'type': 'Buf', 'value': 'v1.0b1s'}]}]}}
Firmware version:  v1.0b1s

<Response [200]>
{'response': {'resultCode': 0, 'data': [{'path': '/EasyIO/int', 'type': 'control::WriteInt', 'childNum': '0', 'slots': [{'name': 'out', 'slotType': 'property', 'type': 'int', 'value': '600'}]}]}}
600
```

To read specific value in json I need to write something like that

```
data['response']['data'][0]['slots'][0]['value']
```

But no idea how to write a post command

This ajax command to write value

```
var url = 'http://192.168.10.11/sdcard/cpt/app/data_api.php';
$.ajax({url: url,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
path: '/app/objects/EasyIO/WriteIn.in',
type: 'int',
value: '100',
slotType: 'property'
}
```

This API documentation: http://gofile.me/32wEs/Tvt9NOMt5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like all you need is this:

```
import requests

uri='http://192.168.10.11/sdcard/cpt/app/data_api.php'
data={'path' : '/app/objects/EasyIO/WriteIn.in', 'type' : 'int', 'value': 100, 'slotType': 'property'}

resp=requests.post(uri,
                   json=data,
                   headers = headers,
                   params = params,
                   cookies = cookies)
```

I don't have a device to test with though, but sending json=data in requests will convert and send the dict as json.